# Tooltip not working correctly with activeIndex on pie charts(ReCharts)

Tags: charts, pie-chart, recharts

Pie charts that utilize Tooltip and activeIndex do not work correctly. The tooltip will not show up unless you re-enter the same sector.
When you are not in the same sector it shows the 
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `activeIndex` supplied to `Pie`.

```
<PieChart
        className="pie-chart"
        width={this.props.width ? this.props.width : 500}
        height={375}
        onMouseEnter={this.onPieEnter}
      >
        <Pie
          dataKey="value"
          data={data}
          // cx={250}
          // cy={100}
          activeIndex={
            this.state.activeIndex === undefined
              ? 0
              : this.state.activeIndex
          }
          activeShape={this.renderActiveShape}
          outerRadius={
            this.state.width <= 1025 && this.state.width > 768 ? 80 : 100
          }
          innerRadius={
            this.state.width <= 1025 && this.state.width > 768 ? 65 : 85
          }
          fill="#8884d8"
          onMouseEnter={this.onPieEnter}
        >
          {data.map((entry, index) => (
            <Cell
              key={index}
              fill={this.COLORS[index % this.COLORS.length]}
            />
          ))}
        </Pie>
</PieChart>
```

Default active index always set so when you are not in the same sector
pie tooltip shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are not in the same sector then the activeIndex is changed automatically and it returns the object type, and actually, activeIndex is number type so I check for a shouldComponentUpdate method and it returns true if activeIndex is number only.

So if the activeIndex type is not a number then component will not be updated and activeIndex state is remains the same as the previous state, so tooltip is not hidden any time.

This code works for me.

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return typeof nextState.activeIndex === "number";
}
```

Comment: is it working for Tooltip?